# Flutter plugin gradle subproject is not resolved by external app project

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have a Flutter plugin project whose Android side is setup to include a third-party `aar` file via gradle module. In order to get the plugin's example app to build, I have to add `include ':aar-module'` to the app's `settings.gradle` file.

The issue arises when I try to include my plugin in the `pubspec.yaml` of an external Flutter app. When I try to build, I'm told that it can't find the third-party aar module. However, if I try to include the aar module in the `settings.gradle` of the Flutter app, it can't find it:

```
Project with path ':aar-module' could not be found in project ':my-plugin'.
```

I tried following the solution on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17150, but it requires hard-coding the module path.

So my question is: How do I include a gradle submodule when its parent is included in a Flutter app (via pubspec)?

If it helps, the `settings.gradle` for the plugin project is the same as the default with the inclusion of the aar module:

```
include ':aar-module'
rootProject.name = 'my-plugin'
```

Comment: Hi @Alex Meuer, did you find a solution for this issue, I am facing the same

Comment: Nothing beyond the answer I posted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, I'm just importing the aar again into the external Flutter android app. It's not ideal because things will break if the aars are out of sync.

I'll refactor the plugin to be part of my Flutter app for now; Having it as a standalone plugin would have been nice but I can't waste too much time on it.